# Split audio without pydub

Tags: python, python-3.8

I need to split an mp3 file into chunks of 30 seconds without pydub.
File 3:38 and last part must be not 30 seconds, just cut every 30 seconds

Comment: You can use another library, or use [specification](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000012.shtml#specs) to get bitrate (kbps) and then split audio data every `bitrate * 30` kilobits. You can take a look at librosa library

Comment: @geobreze I don't understand how to work with sound at all.

Comment: So it's better to use some library. Why don't you want to use pydub?

Comment: @geobreze installing ffmpeg can be difficult for the user.

Comment: pip install pydub works just fine for me

Comment: many modules use ffmpeg - ie. `MoviePy` - so if it may be problem to find module which doesn't use it.

Comment: @geobreze try to explain to the user how to solve the problem with not found file in pydub

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.